# I'm receiving a 408 error after deploying an Elastic Beanstalk app over https

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I setup the certificate, opened the ports and configured django to reply over https in an EBS app.

However, when accessing using https I receive a 408 timeout error. Http access works normally.

How can I get https to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably configured both the load balancer and your app to communicate using https and port 443. Unless you have the special need to secure communication between your load balancer and your app, they should be communicating using http and port 80.

[image: proper configuration]